# Download content of the page using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Greetings, 
how can I download some page content using ajax and jquery:
I am doing something like that (2 versions inside one script):

```
$("p").click(function() {

    $('#result').load('http://google.com');

            $.ajax({
                url='www.google.com',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("result").html(data);
                    alert('Load was performed.');
                    var url = 'www.wp.pl';
                    $('div#result').load(url);
                    //var content = $.load(url);
                    //alert(content);
                    //$("#result").html("test");
                }
            });
});
```

but it does not return any content

Comment: Drop that and use jQuery! Oh wait...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use YQL to proxy your call:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http://www.google.com'&format=xml&callback=callback",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp'
});

  function callback(data){
    $('#result').html(data.results[0]);
  }
```

Comment: I get a blank page with this.

Answer (score 8):

[Due to restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you cannot download the contents of a web page using AJAX that is not hosted on the same domain as the domain hosting this script. Also you have a syntax error in your `.ajax` function call. It should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://yourdomain.com/page1.htm',
    success: function(data) {
        $("result").html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
        var url = 'http://yourdomain.com/page2.htm';
        $('div#result').load(url);
    }
});
```

Comment: is there any way to do this? to get the content of other page?

Comment: you can display the content of another page within an iFrame, but you can't access/read it either.

Comment: Take a look at my answer - it provides a couple of methods to retrieve data external to the current domain.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not possible to directly query a host that is external to the current domain from Javascript, you could use a proxy script to retrieve the desired data.

Cross domain AJAX querying with jQuery: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

You could also make use of the flXHR script, which can be dropped into many Javascript libraries (including jQuery).

flXHR: http://flxhr.flensed.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply call a PHP/ASP/RUby page that in turn does the outside calling for you and presents the information in a way that you need.

```
1.  PAGE --> PHP --> External web
        (Ajax)

2.  PAGE <-- PHP <-- External web
      (callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something called JSONP to go across domain.  Seider has psoted more details on how to do this with jQuery.