# content().find() not working on dynamically inserted url to an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have to double click on submit to get code working after I insert dynamic url to an iframe. It looks like it sets the url in the first click and executes the code on the second.

Code works fine if url is pre inserted there.

Below is the code:

```
$('#search').on('click', 'button', function(){
    var url = $('#url').val();
    $('#url1').attr('src', url);

    var pageLinks = $('#url1').contents().find('#para a');
    alert(pageLinks[1]);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="search">
    <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Enter URL" value="" />
    <button type="button" id="start">START</button>
</div>
<iframe id="url1" style="width:49%;" src="" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
```

url page in iframe has tags like:

```
<p id="para"><a class="alink" href="page-1.php" target="_blank">Link</a></p>
```

This code works but on double click, while I am not able to figure out to do it in a single click.

Comment: the problem is here var pageLinks = $('#url1').contents().find('#para a'); i can't see where is #para id. maybe you have posted more code

Comment: @Doflamingo19, just updated the url page tags in question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours of research I've found the solution.

After dynamically placing url in iframe, it needed to be reloaded.

```
$('#search').on('click', 'button', function(){
    var url = $('#url').val();
    $('#url1').attr('src', url);

    $('#url1').on('load', function () {
        var pageLinks = $('#url1').contents().find('#para a');
        alert(pageLinks[1]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: (change 'search with start'):

```
    $(document).on('click', '#start', function(){
    var url = $('#url').val();
    $('#url1').attr('src', url);

    var pageLinks = $('#url1').contents().find('#para a');
    alert(pageLinks[1]);
});
```

Comment: Hi, replacing `search` with `start`, now its not even adding url to iframe src. :-(

Comment: Even with this code it actually alerts the value on second click. In first click it undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try embedding the iframe in a div element such as below to force refresh the contents of the embedding div element?

HTML

```
<div id="search">
    <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Enter URL" value="" />
    <button type="button" id="start">START</button>
</div>
<div id="iframediv"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#search').on('click', 'button', function(){
    var url = $('#url').val();
    $('#iframediv').html('<iframe style="width:49%;" src="' + url + '" height="200" width="300"></iframe>');

    var pageLinks = $('#iframediv').contents().find('#para a');
    alert(pageLinks[1]);
});
```

Comment: also, "#search" may be changed to "#start" instead as proposed by @Doflamingo19

Comment: I appreciate your help but not working. alerts undefined.

Comment: @DevChauhan Sorry my code didn't help. I slapped your code in codepen.io and found that CORS may possibly be the issue here. I'm also guessing you're trying to perform some sort of screen scraping? In that case, you may want to look at the following URL's:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771870/download-content-of-the-page-using-ajax-jquery

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/client-side-web-scraping-with-javascript-using-jquery-and-regex-5b57a271cb86/

Comment: @DevChauhan also, put the code resolving the page links in a timeout, it's possible that the page has not completed loading into the iframe yet thus causing the undefined values as per your comment in reply to Doflamingo19

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I finally found the solution to it. It needed `$('url1').on('load', function () {'.. I will post the answer soon

Comment: @DevChauhan you're welcome! Glad you got it working. :)